# How to exclude a widget from showing up on a page?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I have a widget that appears on my sidebar throughout my website. I have a page where I don't want this widget to show. How would I go about doing this without installing a plugin and instead doing via hooks or something like that?

Below is code I have modified from another post's answer:

```
function remove_the_scribitwidget ( $regions ) {
if(is_page('sign-up')) {
    $key = array_search("scribit-widget", $regions['sidebar']);
    if($key !== FALSE) {
        unset($regions['sidebar'][$key]);
    }
}
return $regions;
}

add_filter('sidebars_widgets', 'remove_the_scribitwidget');
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in functions.php

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are many plugins for the purpose available:

- [Widget Context](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/)
- [Widgets Controller](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-controller/)
- [Restrict Widgets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-widgets/)
- [Display Widgets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/)
- [JetPack* - by WordPress.com](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/)

<sup>* Will require WordPress.com account to activate the plugin.</sup>

Answer (score -3):

You can do it by creating a page template for that particular page.
Please reffer http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates for more details.

Answer (score -4):

You can use CSS to hide this widget on this particular page.
If your theme uses [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), your page should have the class page-id-# where # is the ID of your page.

In your CSS file, add something like

```
.page-id-# .targeted_widget_class {
  display: none;
}
```